# Change a git commit after a push

Tags: git

I am working with some one who doesn't use git properly and commit messages, whats worse is they do giant commits ...

Is there any thing I can do like changing their commit message to something more readable **after they push** ??

Comment: Not without rewriting global history; do you care about that?

Comment: Unfortunately I do. I have been the only developer and I have a consistent way of doing things and his way is not acceptable and since I don't believe in "running to mommy (daddy)" I am looking for ways in git to handle this ....

Comment: @LogicLooking: pre-receive hook on the server to 1. deny the push, 2. trout-slap the user (/cc @Mitch) - seriously, that's a management problem not a technical one. Talk to the dude, or get "mommy" to look into it if it's actually detrimental to your work (and the talk option failed)

Comment: @Mat I like your idea. Thanks guys.

Comment: If you don't think it's acceptable for someone to write crappy code, then it's not acceptable for them to push crappy commits. It's an education, management problem. Talk to him first, if that doesn't work get a manager to talk to him. If it's affecting your work you shouldn't stand for it.

Answer (score 0):

While others have pointed out, this is a management problem. Nonetheless, if you need to change the history (say if this person leaves the company/project), you're looking for [an interactive rebase](https://help.github.com/articles/interactive-rebase).

Simply run `git rebase -i <SHA of commit before bad commit(s)>` and you'll be prompted via your editor what to do with each commit in the log. You'll want to change the bad commits to `edit` so rebase will stop at each one and allow you to manipulate the state of the repository at that time.

When you're done, you'll need to force push (`git push -f`) to your remote and any branches from the commits you modified will become detached. In other words, it will likely be noticed that you did this. Again, I would recommend taking the human approach to this, rather than the technical one.

Comment: You should also point out that this changes history and is likely to break repositories that have previously cloned from this one. Only do it if everyone is willing to re-clone from this repo.